# splice on for loop and change the index number of the activity

Tags: javascript, html

i have a variable like this:

```
deftemplate = {
    "activities":["Earthworks", "Concrete Works", "Steel Works", "Framework", "MansoryWorks", "Carpentry Works", "Roofing Works", "Pre-Fabricated Works", "Painting Works", "Plumbing", "Electrical Works"],
    "tasks":[
    // Earthworks
        {"taskname":"Clearing and Grubbing", "activity":0, "parent":null, "notifyclient":false, "days":5, "manpower":[[1, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 2]], "materials":[[1, 0, 0, 3]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Excavation", "activity":0, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":12, "manpower":4, "materials":[[1, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 3]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Soil Poisoning", "activity":0, "parent":1, "notifyclient":false, "days":5, "manpower":[[6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Gravel Bedding", "activity":0, "parent":2, "notifyclient":false, "days":5, "manpower":[[6, 0, 0, 2]], "materials":[], "equipments":[]},

    // Concrete Works
        {"taskname":"Footings", "activity":1, "parent":3, "notifyclient":false, "days":7, "manpower":[[2, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 3], [9, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[2, 0, 0, 49], [4, 0, 0, 2], [5, 0, 0, 4]], "equipments":[[3, 0, 0, 1]]},
        {"taskname":"Columns", "activity":1, "parent":4, "notifyclient":false, "days":15, "manpower":[[3, 0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0, 3], [6, 0, 0, 5]], "materials":[[2, 0, 0, 75], [4, 0, 0, 5], [5, 0, 0, 10]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Beams", "activity":1, "parent":5, "notifyclient":false, "days":11, "manpower":[[3, 0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 0, 3], [6, 0, 0, 5]], "materials":[[2, 0, 0, 55], [4, 0, 0, 4.5], [5, 0, 0, 9]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Slabs", "activity":1, "parent":6, "notifyclient":false, "days":8, "manpower":[[2, 0, 0, 2], [3, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 4]], "materials":[[2, 0, 0, 52], [4, 0, 0, 4.5], [5, 0, 0, 9]], "equipments":[]},

    // Steel Works
        {"taskname":"Footings", "activity":2, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":4, "manpower":[[11, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[6, 0, 0, 25]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Columns", "activity":2, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":22, "manpower":[[7, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[6, 0, 0, 68], [7, 0, 0, 145], [8, 0, 0, 285]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Beams", "activity":2, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":19, "manpower":[[7, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[6, 0, 0, 57], [7, 0, 0, 105], [8, 0, 0,150]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Slabs", "activity":2, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":10, "manpower":[[7, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[8, 0, 0, 165]], "equipments":[]},

    // Framework
        {"taskname":"Formworks and Scaffoldings", "activity":3, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":35, "manpower":[[6, 0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 0, 5]], "materials":[[9, 0, 0, 1050], [10, 0, 0, 75]], "equipments":[]},

    // Mansoryworks
        {"taskname":"Masonry", "activity":4, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":41, "manpower":[[2, 0, 0, 5], [6, 0, 0, 3]], "materials":[[11, 0, 0, 1042], [12, 0, 0, 469]], "equipments":[]},

    // Carpentry Works
        {"taskname":"Ceilings, Cabinets and Etc.", "activity":5, "parent":13, "notifyclient":false, "days":31, "manpower":[[7, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[10, 0, 0, 56], [13, 0, 0, 235]], "equipments":[]},

    // Roofing Works
        {"taskname":"Roofing Materials, Trusses and etc", "activity":6, "parent":14, "notifyclient":false, "days":12, "manpower":[[3, 0, 0, 5], [6, 0, 0, 3]], "materials":[[14, 0, 0, 17], [15, 0, 0, 1292], [16, 0, 0, 138]], "equipments":[]},

    // Pre-Fabriacted Works
        {"taskname":"Doors", "activity":7, "parent":15, "notifyclient":false, "days":9, "manpower":[[3, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 2]], "materials":[[17, 0, 0, 2]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Windows", "activity":7, "parent":16, "notifyclient":false, "days":9, "manpower":[[3, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 2]], "materials":[[17, 0, 0, 14]], "equipments":[]},

    // Painting Works
        {"taskname":"Exterior", "activity":8, "parent":17, "notifyclient":false, "days":24, "manpower":[[8, 0, 0, 4]], "materials":[[18, 0, 0, 10], [19, 0, 0, 3], [20, 0, 0, 1], [21, 0, 0, 5], [22, 0, 0, 3]], "equipments":[]},

    // Plumbing ---
        {"taskname":"Fixtures", "activity":9, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":2, "manpower":[[5, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[23, 0, 0, 1], [24, 0, 0, 22], [25, 0, 0, 22], [26, 0, 0, 22]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Waterlines", "activity":9, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":12, "manpower":[[5, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[27, 0, 0, 5], [28, 0, 0, 20], [29, 0, 0, 3]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Sanitary Sewerline", "activity":9, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":12, "manpower":[[5, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[30, 0, 0, 4], [31, 0, 0, 3], [32, 0, 0, 2]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Storm Drain", "activity":9, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":12, "manpower":[[5, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[31, 0, 0, 15]], "equipments":[]},

    // Electrical Works ---
        {"taskname":"Fixtures and Boxes", "activity":10, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":3, "manpower":[[4, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[33, 0, 0, 3], [34, 0, 0, 1]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Fittings", "activity":10, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":5, "manpower":[[4, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 2]], "materials":[[35, 0, 0, 100]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Wiring", "activity":10, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":10, "manpower":[[4, 0, 0, 2], [6, 0, 0, 2]], "materials":[[36, 0, 0, 5]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Enclosed Circuit Breaker", "activity":10, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":2, "manpower":[[4, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[[37, 0, 0, 8]], "equipments":[]},
        {"taskname":"Testing and Commissioning", "activity":10, "parent":0, "notifyclient":false, "days":2, "manpower":[[4, 0, 0, 1], [6, 0, 0, 1]], "materials":[], "equipments":[]},
    ]
};
```

and i have the code to delete a specific activity here:

```
function delact(event) {
var curact = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("curact"));
deftemplate["activities"].splice(curact, 1);
for (var d = 0; d < deftemplate["tasks"].length; d++) {
    if (deftemplate["tasks"][d]["activity"] == curact) {
        for (var g = 0; g < deftemplate["tasks"][d]["equipments"].length; g++) {
            restoreCount2(deftemplate["tasks"][d]["equipments"][g][0], deftemplate["tasks"][d]["equipments"][g][1]);
        }

        for (var g = 0; g < deftemplate["tasks"][d]["manpower"].length; g++) {
            restoremCount2(deftemplate["tasks"][d]["manpower"][g][0], deftemplate["tasks"][d]["manpower"][g][1]);
        }

        for (var y = 0; y < deftemplate["tasks"].length; y++) {
            if (deftemplate["tasks"][y]["parent"] == d) {
                deftemplate["tasks"][y]["parent"] = null;
            }
            if (deftemplate["tasks"][y]["activity"] > curact) {
                console.log("Task Name: " + deftemplate["tasks"][y]["taskname"]);
                deftemplate["tasks"][y]["activity"]--;
            }
        }
        deftemplate["tasks"].splice(d, 1);
    }
}
loadacts($("#prjstartdate").val());
}
```

The problem is the task is connected to the activities variable by an index. When you delete a specific activity in the "activities" variable the task activity index more than the activity deleted index needs to be decreased by 1 to be arranged to the activities variable again but my code doesn't seem to work. How can i fix this code?

Comment: please give an example, what you like to delete. and what should happen.

Comment: http://112.206.109.164/thesis2 login user:admin password:password. go to project, add project, select a start date, delete an activity and you can see my problem. Thanks!

Comment: i do not delete something. whats more interesting what items are dependent.

Comment: You can always do d-- after the splice.

Comment: I already tried that but it didnt work.

Comment: God this code can fail in so many ways. **You really need a better data-structure!** Better use static IDs and/or reference the corresponding task-objects instead of this mess with continuously changing indices.

Comment: @Thomas it is in the client side (javascript) code I can't use SQL on javascript. there is really no other way to do it. even localStorage won't solve the problem. and I need to generate the JSON of it to send it to the server side and save it on my relational sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the for loop where you decrease the activity.  If i am reading the code right the problem is that after you press a button every activity after that one is deleted.

The solution is to do another for loop after you are done deleting items, and decrease the activity there.  You also need to lower d by 1 with a d--

```html
var curact = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute("curact"));
deftemplate["activities"].splice(curact, 1);
for (var d = 0; d < deftemplate["tasks"].length; d++) {
    if (deftemplate["tasks"][d]["activity"] == curact) {
        for (var g = 0; g < deftemplate["tasks"][d]["equipments"].length; g++) {
            restoreCount2(deftemplate["tasks"][d]["equipments"][g][0], deftemplate["tasks"][d]["equipments"][g][1]);
        }

        for (var g = 0; g < deftemplate["tasks"][d]["manpower"].length; g++) {
            restoremCount2(deftemplate["tasks"][d]["manpower"][g][0], deftemplate["tasks"][d]["manpower"][g][1]);
        }

        for (var y = 0; y < deftemplate["tasks"].length; y++) {
            if (deftemplate["tasks"][y]["parent"] == d) {
                deftemplate["tasks"][y]["parent"] = null;
            }
        deftemplate["tasks"].splice(d, 1);
        d--;
    }
}
for(var y = 0; y < deftemplate["tasks"].length; y++){
  if (deftemplate["tasks"][y]["activity"] > curact) {
    console.log("Task Name: " + deftemplate["tasks"][y]["taskname"]);
    deftemplate["tasks"][y]["activity"]--;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I already fixed it with the exact code you gave before i even read your answer :)

Comment: how is it different from my proposal?

Comment: The y for loop was decreasing all of the activity numbers down to equal the activity number being deleted, which means if you were trying to delete activity 2, every activity after that was also being deleted.  You weren't wrong about d--, but that wasn't the only issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
deftemplate["tasks"].splice(d, 1);
```

and the `for` loop. When you delete an item, the next item is at the same slot. Then the `for` increments the index and the index before is skipped.

Conclusion: Decrement `d` after splicing.

```
deftemplate["tasks"].splice(d, 1);
d--;
```

<sub>(I suggest a better data structure.)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing items from an array then you should iterate backwards.

```
for (var d = deftemplate["tasks"].length -1; d >= 0; d--) {
    // deftemplate["tasks"][d] can be removed...
}
```